# Eigenvalues of sum $\lambda_i(X(D_1 + D_2)X^T) = \lambda_{\sigma_1(i)}(XD_1X^T) + \lambda_{\sigma_2(i)}(XD_2X^T)$ where $D_1, D_2$ are diagonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, singular-values

Let $D_1, D_2\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$ be positive definite diagonal matrices. Let $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ satisfy $\text{rank}(X) = n < d$. Is it true that
$$\lambda_i(X(D_1+D_2)X^T) = \lambda_{\sigma_1(i)}(XD_1X^T) + \lambda_{\sigma_2(i)}(XD_2X^T),$$
for some bijections $\sigma_1,\sigma_2:\{1,\dots,n\} \longrightarrow \{1,\dots,n\}$? Here, $\lambda_i(\cdot)$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ largest eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

For most such matrices $X,D_1,D_2$, this statement will not hold. As an example, take
$$
X = \pmatrix{0&1&2\\3&4&5}, \quad D_1 = \pmatrix{\epsilon\\&1\\&&\epsilon}, \quad D_2 = \pmatrix{1\\&\epsilon\\&&\epsilon}
$$
For a sufficiently small $\epsilon > 0$.

If we take $\epsilon = 0$, the eigenvalues of the matrices are:

- $XD_1X^T: 0,17$
- $XD_2X^T: 0,9$
- $X(D_1 + D_2)X^T: 0.35088936, 25.64911064$.

It is clear that there is no suitable bijection in the case that $\epsilon = 0$. By the continuity of eigenvalues, it follows that a suitable bijection also does not exist for a sufficiently small $\epsilon > 0$ (for example, $\epsilon = 0.01$ works).

---

Suppose that $Y$ is a matrix that is close to $X$ such that $YY^T$ is a multiple of the identity (i.e. its rows are orthogonal and of equal length). The condition
$$
\lambda_i(Y(D_1+D_2)Y^T) = \lambda_{\sigma_1(i)}(YD_1Y^T) + \lambda_{\sigma_2(i)}(YD_2Y^T)
$$
will hold for some bijections $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$. On the other hand, for a diagonal matrix $D$, we have
$$
XDX^T - Y^TDY = (X + (Y - X))D(X + (Y-X))^T  - X^TDX\\
= XD(Y-X)^T + (Y-X)^TDX + (Y-X)D(Y-X)^T,
$$
so that
$$
\|XDX^T - YDY^T\| = \|XD(Y-X)^T + (Y-X)^TDX + (Y-X)D(Y-X)^T\|
\\ \leq 2 \|X\| \cdot \|D\| \cdot \|X-Y\| + \|D\|\cdot \|X-Y\|^2,
$$
where $\|X\|$ denotes the spectral norm (maximal singular value) of $X$. If we know that $\|X - Y\| \leq \|X\|$, we can weaken this bound to $\|XDX^T - YDY^T\| \leq 3 \|X\| \cdot \|D\| \cdot \|X-Y\|$.

With this weaker bound, we have
$$
|\lambda_i(XDX^T) - \lambda_i(YDY^T)| \leq \|XDX^T - YDY^T\|  \leq 3 \|X\| \cdot \|D\| \cdot \|X-Y\|.
$$
Putting this all together, we can get the bound
$$
|\lambda_i(X(D_1+D_2)X^T) - (\lambda_{\sigma_1(i)}(XD_1X^T) 
 + \lambda_{\sigma_2(i)}(XD_2X^T))| \leq \\
9 \|X\|\,\|D_1 + D_2\|\,\|X-Y\|.
$$

Comment: That's great, thank you! The eigenvalues seem pretty close to what you would expect if $n=d$ and X was orthonormal. Is it possible to obtain a bound on $\lambda_i(X(D_1+D_2)X^T) - (\lambda_{\sigma_1(i)}(XD_1X^T) + \lambda_{\sigma_2(i)}(XD_2X^T))$ in the case $n<d$?

Comment: @vladye We can get some kind of bound if $X$ is "close" to having orthogonal rows of equal norm; I give one such bound in my latest edit. I'm not sure how much better we can do than this.

Comment: Excellent @Ben Grossmanm, this is exactly what I need. I am able to bound $|\sigma_{\text{max}}(X) - 1|$ and $|1 - \sigma_{\text{min}}(X)|$. Could you please help me with two points in your argument? Why is it clear that if Y has orthonormal rows (but $n<d$) then the statement with the eigenvalues is true? My intuition is that this happens if $YD_1Y^T$ and $YD_2Y^T$ commute (see e.g. Theorem 7 here https://www.math.drexel.edu/~foucart/TeachingFiles/F12/M504Lect2.pdf). The second thing is that I struggle proving $|\lambda_i(XDX^T) - \lambda_i(YDY^T)| \leq \sigma_{\text{max}}(XDX^T - YDY^T)$

Comment: @vladye Orthonormal rows **of equal length** (i.e. equal norm). In that case, there is some $k \in \Bbb R$ and $U$ with orthonormal rows such that $Y = kU$; perhaps you can fill in the rest. You can also show that in this case, $YD_1Y^T$ and $YD_2Y^T$ commute.

Comment: @vladye There are a few approaches regarding your second point; one is to use [Weyl's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality).

Comment: I did some numerical simulations with random orthogonal matrices (using scipy.stats.ortho_group in python) and I don't think $YD_1Y^T$ and $YD_2Y^T$ commute even if $YY^T = I_n$. Can one work around this (assuming I haven't made a mistake)? @Ben Grossmann

Comment: I think I had in mind that if $Y^TY = I$, then $YD_1Y^T$ and $YD_2Y^T$ commute. I'm not sure how my approach could be fixed

Comment: It's an interesting phenomenon. Even though $\lambda_i(Y(D_1+D_2)Y^T) = \lambda_{\sigma_1(i)}(YD_1Y^T) + \lambda_{\sigma_2(i)}(YD_2Y^T)$ is not true, the numerical simulations show that it is very close to being true (error can be $~0.01$ for evals of size $~1$). If the approach you wrote down worked, it completely solves my research problem. Hence if it is possible (and the simulations hint it is) to have good bound on $\lambda_i(Y(D_1+D_2)Y^T) - (\lambda_{\sigma_1(i)}(YD_1Y^T) + \lambda_{\sigma_2(i)}(YD_2Y^T))$ then we are done. @Ben Grossmann